# How do I set the domain parameters in Google Analytics for cn1 analytics service

Tags: codenameone

How do I set the domain when my cn1 app calls AnalyticsService.init? Is the domain of init parameter control center->basic->package name?

Comment: It's the domain you see when you created the analytics account. I don't think it matters that much and is mostly for your convenience.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand.
There is no data sent to Google Analytics when the domain parameter of AnalyticsService.init is set as the domain of Google Analytics resources.

Comment: I'm not up to date on the current analytics UI. Can you add a screenshot of the configuration? Did you create an app version of analytics?

Comment: I only find information about GA4 for the mobile apps. So I build a resource for trying to connect with cn1 app. But it doesn't work.  Would you provide detailed information about  AnalyticsService?
Does cn1 plan to support GA4?

Comment: We don't have any immediate plans for that, haven't looked into it yet.